# retrieving dyamically created html input textboxes when form is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating an `HTML` form dynamically using `php`.
The name of an `input` box on the `html` `form` is also dynamically created.
When I hit `submit` on the dynamically created `html` `form` and use the method `post` to push the data to the server.
How can I call the name of the dynamically created `input` box on the action page of the `form`?
In other words how can I get the  name of my `input` box passed to my `php` `form` when I click `submit` if I have code like below?

```
function add_textbox($label, $name) {
    myprint("<label>$label <br><br><input type=text name=$name onblur = \"anschecker(this.value)\"></label><br><br>");
}
```

Comment: you could do "foreach($_POST as $data_form) { //stuff}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST)){
       foreach($_POST as $value){
          echo $value; //here you will get the values of each field in the form
        }  
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be passed with the code you have.

If you want to find the name in your PHP code that it gets passed to you might want to use a statement like the one I will make below.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    // The key will be the name of the value passed in this loop.
}
```